# When using render method, stream flash messages are not flushed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, streaming, turbolinks

I have an issue where the session controller is running:

```
redirect_to dashboard_path
notice: 'logged_in'
```

And the dashboard is basically:

```
def index
    render stream: true
end
```

What seems to be happening is with chunked encoding, the flash is not being reset so the messages are sticky. I have these flash messages just before the `yield` so perhaps it is due to the rendering process. Anyone have advice on how to deal with this?

Comment: Can you please explain it in more detail. It is not clear what you want

Comment: So the issue is. A user(me) will login which redirects to the dashboard controller on success. This then shows the dashboard and a flash message that basically says 'logged in' (It happens with any flash message).

When I visit another page or refresh, the flash message remains. This happens when I have ```render stream: true``` on the controller. They disappear when chunked encoding is disabled suggesting that flash messages are not flushed before the action starts.

Comment: Also, maybe you want to add your code. Should be `flash[:notice] = 'logged in' `and before the `redirect_to` and `<%= flash[:notice] %>`.

Comment: I have flash messages before redirects as you show and inline. The issue persists as long as render stream is true.

Comment: Did you already try `flash.now`?

Comment: Yep on flash.now. It does not clear when using render stream

Comment: Take a look here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html _When streaming, the HTTP headers are sent to the client right before it renders the first line. This means that, modifying headers, cookies, session or flash after the template starts rendering will not propagate to the client._

Comment: Thanks for that iGian, so the question changes. How do other Rails developers handle the flash when we are doing chunked encoding?